# Django runserver error after startproject

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, frameworks

I'm new to Django and web frameworks in general. Right off the bat, I can't seem to run the server after django-admin startproject mytestsite. I've tried this with and without a virtual environment, and with Python's built-in virtual environment tool as well as virtualenv.

This is the error I get:

```
(my_django_environment) MacBook-Pro:mytestsite alialsabbah1$ python3 manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x108caef28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/alialsabbah/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

I'm not really sure where to even start with this.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994449/symbol-not-found-sqlite3-enable-load-extension-sqlite-installed-via-homebrew)

Comment: You should be in the path that manage.py file on there. then run command 'python manage.py runserver'

Comment: Selcuk, your link worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbol not found: \_sqlite3\_enable\_load\_extension - sqlite installed via homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994449/symbol-not-found-sqlite3-enable-load-extension-sqlite-installed-via-homebrew)